# Biojava sample run with ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, jvm, bioinformatics, biojava

I've tried to run a very simple sample `BioJava` copy&pase from wikipedia.

```
package test;    
import org.biojava.nbio.data.sequence.FastaSequence;
import org.biojava.nbio.ronn.Jronn;

    public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FastaSequence fsequence = new FastaSequence("Prot1", "LLRGRHLMNGTMIMRPWNFLNDHHFPKFFPHLIEQQAIWLADWWRKKHC" +
                "RPLPTRAPTMDQWDHFALIQKHWTANLWFLTFPFNDKWGWIWFLKDWTPGSADQAQRACTWFFCHGHDTN" +
                "CQIIFEGRNAPERADPMWTGGLNKHIIARGHFFQSNKFHFLERKFCEMAEIERPNFTCRTLDCQKFPWDDP");
        Jronn.Range[] ranges = Jronn.getDisorder(fsequence);
    }
}
```

However, when I run it I get the following exception:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at test.Run.main(Run.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
    at org.biojava.nbio.ronn.ModelLoader.loadModels(ModelLoader.java:188)
    at org.biojava.nbio.ronn.Jronn.<clinit>(Jronn.java:55)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Version:

```
"biojava-protein-disorder"  4.1.0
```

Comment: I recommend posting this to the biojava mailing list. It could be a bug in their wrapper parser.  I don't know anything about RONN but the biojava code might be parsing the output RONN file incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an issue with java 8 that was solved in 4.2. Could you try the latest release of biojava (4.2.1)?